# Generate an array of random numbers not present in a list dart

Tags: random, flutter, dart

so i have a list of predefined numbers where each number consists of 6 numbers like this {1,2,3,4,5,6 ; 34,52,3,76,12,4 ; 53,1,4,76,23,5 ; .... }

each individual number in the group of numbers range from 1 to 99,

```
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var rng = new Random();
  var l = new List.generate(12, (_) => rng.nextInt(100));
}
```

i want to generate an array of 6 different random numbers using dart in a way that it is not already present in the list of numbers i already have.

Comment: can you have {1,2,3,4,5,6; 1,2,3,4,5,6} ? and how many groups of 6 numbers ?

Comment: no each sequence can only appear once in the list like a special serial number
so in other words i need each generated sequence to be different than any of the sequences already in the list of previous number sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {  
    var listOfSets = List<Set<int>>();

    final int nElementsWithMax = 99;  
    final int kTaken = 6;    
    final int requiredResults = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < requiredResults; i++) {
      bool isInList = false;
      Set<int> anewSet;
      do {
        anewSet = Set.of(listRandom(nElementsWithMax, kTaken));
        isInList = listOfSets.firstWhere(
                (setInList) => anewSet.intersection(setInList).length == anewSet.length,
            orElse: () => null)
            != null;
      } while (isInList);
      listOfSets.add(anewSet);
    }
    print(listOfSets);
}

List<int> listRandom(int maxNumber, int numberOfGenerations) {

  final random = Random();
  var currentOptions = List<int>.generate(maxNumber, (i) => i);

  var list = List.generate(numberOfGenerations, (_) {
    final index = random.nextInt(currentOptions.length);
    final result = currentOptions[index];
    currentOptions.removeAt(index);    
    return result;
  });
  return list;
}
```

Keep in mind that you cannot exceed the combination limit defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

In your case, **requiredResults** cannot exceed (100!)/((6! * (100 - 6)!) ... some huge number

Comment: that worked greatt... but how can i make it in a way that i declare a list with some predefined sequences and make the function generate a new sequence with at least one different number

Comment: Did update, please recheck. I suppose the order of the elements does not matter and also if you want to use Lists instead of Sets that can also be changed easily

Comment: thank you very much that worked as i wanted...  i appreciate that, im new at dart so this really helped me a lot
thanks again